# Mark Up Formatting of Titles & Questions

Tags: feature-request

I edited [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/whats-the-most-cost-effective-cutter-bit-material-that-can-be-used-to-machine) because the OP originally had Al2O3, with no numbers subscripted, instead of Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>.

When I reformatted the chemical using

```
     Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>
```

The correct formatting appeared in the body of the text but not the title. The title displayed `Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>`, not Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>.

To get the chemical displayed in the title with the numbers subscripted I had to use conventional MathJax formatting,

$\small\sf\{Al_2O_3}$

Does anyone know why using the `<sub> </sub>` pair will not work in titles?

Answer (score 2):

[As discussed on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82013/254929), HTML tags such as `<sub>` are not rendered in question titles across the network. This has its origin on Stack Overflow, where it would not be more common to want to ask a question *about the HTML element itself* than to need to use it to format the title.

If, when asking a question, you think it would be a significant improvement to the readability of the title to have subscripts or superscripts, you can try using [Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

I've edited that question so that the title simply reads "aluminum oxide," which is going to be the most consistently readable option. I expect that someone searching for "al2o3" should still be able to get a hit from the question body. The reason for avoiding MathJax in titles is that every page that has to render any amount of MathJax must first load MathJax.js, which [significantly increases the page load time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on/252283#252283). Question titles appear in a lot more places than question bodies; a new or active question with MathJax in the title is going to slow down our front page for *everyone*, so it's a bit of a non-starter.